# Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password error while installing MYSQL

Tags: mysql

While installing MYSQL i got this error "MySQL error 0: Reading from the stream has failed.
Waiting 3 seconds before the next connection attempt...
  Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password..."
Finished configuration of MySQL Server 8.0.13 with state ConfigurationError

I have provided the password still it is showing no password,, i have also googled it but unable to find anything useful. Please help me with this issue

[image: Screenshot of my MYSQL configuration part]

Comment: Is your MYSQL Server Service is running?

Comment: Yes , the service was running

Comment: My suggestion is uninstall all related MYSQL and reinstall it again.